# Search array field data in hstore Rails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, hstore

Using **hstore**, storing data like

```
properties = {"1"=>"Test", "2"=["One","Two","Three"]}
```

Need to create filter in which I want to search array value like if I put 2=>"One" or 2=> "one", "two" so it should sent me this record. I have read `hstore` gem wikki but could not found any data related io it.

Comment: hstore isn't a structured type. You probably want `jsonb`, which supports nested structure. In `hstore` that array will just be a blob.

Comment: @CraigRinger it means we can not search data mention in array ?